# Возврат содержимого экрана в прежнее состояние после возвращения из фрагмента

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Проблема следующая. В приложении есть фрагмент со списком элементов. При нажатии на элемент открывается другой фрагмент с подробным описанием выбранного элемента. При возврате на предыдущий фрагмент (то есть на фрагмент со списком всех элементов) список загружается заново, т.к. это действие прописано в методе `onResume()`. Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы при возврате на фрагмент со всеми элементами список не загружался заново, а чтобы на экране было все точно так же, как до нажатия на элемент списка, например, как это происходит в приложениях интернет-магазинов. Каким образом я могу это реализовать?

Comment: Загружать в `onCreate` вместо `onResume`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо, упустил этот момент